# How to change a list of values into variables?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list `{E, {p, ϕ}}`, and I need values `E`, `p`, and `ϕ` such that I can later on do operations with them (like `ArcCos[p]`, etc.). I will be repeatedly generating the values in the list, as a list, so doing this by-hand is not an option. How do I get them out of the list?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Take a look at the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/WorkWithLists.html). BTW `[Phi] ` is invalid syntax. Is it a string "[Phi]"?

Comment: You probably want [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) (i.e. `[[ ... ]]`. For instance, if `list =  {E, {p, ϕ}}`, then `list[[2, 1]]` returns the value of `p`, so you could use `ArcCos[ list[[2, 1]] ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let:

```
list = {a, {b,c}};
```

This will give you element "a":

```
list[[1]]
```

This will give you elements {b,c}:

```
list[[2]]
```

This will give you "b" straight away:

```
list[[2, 1]]
```